# How can you search tweets on specific topic / hashtag using Watson Discovery?

Tags: php, database, twitter, ibm-cloud, watson

I made a Bluemix cloud account and am trying to use the Watson Discovery API. I noticed that Watson Discovery has its own database from where it searches for information. Can I use Watson Discovery to look for specific keywords or hashtags and display them on my website?

Answer (score 0):

Limit the documents you search to tweets by including this filter ....

```
 filter(entities.text:twitter)
```

Comment: which data collection should i use ? the default watson discovery news ? or should i create a new one ?

Comment: Depends.  Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  By using the default News feed, which is updated daily, you remain current.  If however, you are trying to collect data and perform further processing on it, you may be better served by a custom collection.  So, the bigger question is ... what are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I'm actually trying to stay current, but does the default News feed even support Twitter ?